# Pandas creating a new column based on a condition in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df_1` like below :

```
|  A       |  B        |
+----------+-----------+
|A         |  120.0    |
|D         |  2.50     |
|N         |  1.00     |
|N         |  0.50     |
|D         |  1.50     |
|A         |  240.0    |
+----------+-----------+
```

And I have another dataframe `df_2` like below :

```
|  J        |  K       |  L        | M         |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  0.50     |   4.1    |   70.0    |  55.0     |
|  0.75     |   6.7    |   80.0    |  66.0     |
|  1.00     |   8.2    |   90.0    |  95.0     |
|  1.50     |   9.6    |   120.0   |  186.0    |
|  2.50     |   10.7   |   240.0   |  188.0    |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The goal is to create a new column called `Z` in the `df_1` where in we lookup the values of column B (`df_1`) in df_2 based on the condition in column A (`df_1`).For example, in column Z as show below , the value of A is 186.0 which is obtained by looking up the value 120.0 (in `df_1`) in the columns L and M in `df_2`.Similarly, the values for D,N are obtained by looking in the columns J and K respectively. The final dataframe looks like below

```
|  A       |  B        |  Z      |
+----------+-----------+----------
|A         |  120.0    | 186.0   |
|D         |  2.50     | 10.7    |
|N         |  1.00     | 8.2     |
|N         |  0.50     | 4.1     |
|D         |  1.50     | 9.6     |
|A         |  240.0    | 188.0   |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

So, how can the above be achieved in Pandas similar to how we can achieve in Excel vlookup ?

EDIT :
What if the `df_2` looked like below ? Can we still get the same results as above ?

```
|  J        |  K       |  L        | M         |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  0.50     |   4.1    |   70.0    |  55.0     |
|  0.75     |   6.7    |   80.0    |  66.0     |
|  1.00     |   8.2    |   90.0    |  95.0     |
|  1.50     |   9.6    |   120.0   |  186.0    |
|  2.50     |   10.7   |   240.0   |  188.0    |
|  3.50     |   2.2    |   NaN     |  NaN      |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: In your `final_dataframe` - Why the values in column `B` is different from the original?

Comment: I have corrected it. It's a typo

Comment: It's corrected now

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df1['c'] = df1.B.map(dict(df2.values.reshape(-1,2)))
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
            A      B      c
1  A           120.0  186.0
2  D             2.5   10.7
3  N             1.0    8.2
4  N             0.5    4.1
5  D             1.5    9.6
6  A           240.0  188.0
```

Complete example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1: 'A', 2: 'D', 3: 'N', 4: 'N', 5: 'D', 6: 'A'},
                    'B': {1: 120.0, 2: 2.5, 3: 1.0, 4: 0.5, 5: 1.5, 6: 240.0}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'J': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.75, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.5, 4: 2.5},
                    'K': {0: 4.1, 1: 6.7, 2: 8.2, 3: 9.6, 4: 10.7},
                    'L': {0: 70.0, 1: 80.0, 2: 90.0, 3: 120.0, 4: 240.0},
                    'M': {0: 55.0, 1: 66.0, 2: 95.0, 3: 186.0, 4: 188.0}})

df1['c'] = df1.B.map(dict(df2.values.reshape(-1, 2)))
```

Comment: Hey, it worked - what if the df2 looked like below and if we were to apply the same operation ? i.e if we had NaN values in last row of L and M and we had values in J and K

|  J           |  K        |  L         | M         |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+
|  0.50     |   4.1    |   70.0    |  55.0     |
|  0.75     |   6.7    |   80.0    |  66.0     |
|  1.00     |   8.2    |   90.0    |  95.0     |
|  1.50     |   9.6    |   120.0  |  186.0   |
|  2.50     |   10.7  |   240.0  |  188.0   |
| 3.50      |   9.9    |    NaN  |   NaN    |  
+--------+-------+--------+--------+